# CSS floated elements not sitting next to each other

Tags: css

Please take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/yCrA8/

The blue sidebar should float next to red middle box but instead it's clearing it and sitting below...

How do I fix this? I can't set a width for the .Middle div because it has content that needs to flow outside of the browser view and be scrollable.

Cheers

Comment: First of all id put it all into tidy CSS. Trying to debug that is a CSS nightmare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yCrA8/4/

One way is to use `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.

Remove `float: left` from `.Sidebar` and `.Middle`, then add this:

```
.MainContent {
    white-space: nowrap
}
.Sidebar, .Middle {
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    /* if you need ie6/7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

Comment: One problem! The red content now goes all the way to edge of the browser and loses the margin provided by the maincontent.

Comment: Another problem: in IE7 and older, inline-block is only supported on elements with "display:inline" by default. So you should change your divs to spans or something like it.

Comment: @Cameron: The simplest way to add right margin is to add `.Middle { margin-right: 20px }`.

Comment: @Hierow: Actually testing my answer, it doesn't quite work in IE7 - but that's not the reason for it. `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1` makes it work on `div`s in IE6/7.

Comment: vertical-align: top; - easy to miss when doing display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

@Camernon; there is a reason why your `middle` div is not wrap because you did not define `width` to your `middle` div for this you can define width your `middle` & it's `parent div`

CSS:

```
.Middle
    {
        background:red;
        width:9125px;
        float:left;
    }

.MainContent
        {
            margin: 20px;
            width: 9330px;
        }
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/yCrA8/11/